# Does the correlation amongst stocks rise when stock values decline?

Tags: volatility, correlation, correlation-matrix, garch

Is there any research on whether the correlations among stocks rise when stock indices decline? Which model could account and test for that effect ? Maybe GARCH-BEKK, or some models using copulas?

Comment: Conditional correlations do rise (this can be show via a simple R simulation) when overall volatility increases. It would be interesting to see if research if the unconditional correlations rise as well

Comment: I believe I've read that unconditional correlation increases also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably be interested in the following papers:

- Ang & Chen: [Asymmetric Correlations of Equity Portfolios](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=219495)
- Longin & Solnik: [Extreme Correlation of International Equity Markets](http://www.clsbe.lisboa.ucp.pt/resources/documents/PROFESSORES/seminarios/JoFLonginBSolnik.pdf)
- Hong et al: [Asymmetric Correlation of Stock Returns:
  Statistical Tests and Economic Evaluation](http://www.afajof.org/pdfs/2004program/updf/p660_asset_pricing.pdf)

The last paper goes further into exploring the implications of asymmetric correlation on portfolio selection and investor utility.

As you mention, GARCH-based methods like BEKK or DCC can address time-varying correlation and copulas are a good way to capture asymmetric dependence more generally.